# Can I use my Surface 3 as an external drawing tablet?

Tags: windows-8.1, mouse, microsoft-surface, input-device, drawing

I have a Microsoft Surface 3 (not pro) with the Surface Pen stylus.  I am wondering if I can use my Surface as an external drawing tablet (input device) for my desktop computer (running win 8.1 pro).  This will entail the Surface sending mouse location, click, and pressure to the desktop; ideally with the desktop duplicating the screen to the surface as well (though not absolutely necessary).

I asked a guy a the local Best Buy and he said all I needed to do was get a USB to HDMI cable and plug the USB into the Surface and the HDMI into the desktop.  After a bit of research online I have found several other people trying to do what I am trying to do, but no relevant answers, let alone anything having to do with a USB/HDMI cable.

Though I am not sure this is relevant, I did find [one person](http://www.reddit.com/r/Surface/comments/21nvzt/can_the_surface_pro_be_used_as_a_drawing_tablet/) that claimed that the Surfaces use Wacom technology.

So is this possible?  And if so how do I do it?

Comment: Surface Pro and SP2 used Wacom, but SP3 switched to N-Trig and the Surface 3 uses the same too (MS bought the tech from N-Trig).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the surface like a wacon tablet the answer is not, you can't use your surface as a second monitor of your pc.

But you want to do something like a tech MacGyver you can download a remote desktop application like Team Viewer, put in fullscreen and use both displays to use at your pc apps with the surface stylus.